# Handling timezone when parsing date in Java 6

Tags: java, parsing, date, simpledateformat, java-6

I am trying to parse/validate the date `2013-06-19T12:00-05:00` using Java 6

I have tried several patterns, including following:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmz
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm Z
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm z
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'z'
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm-Z
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm-z
yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ
yyyy-mm-DD'T'hh:mm:ssZ
yyyy-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ssZ
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz
```

but keep getting `ParseException`.

What would be the appropriate format/pattern for parsing `2013-06-19T12:00-05:00`?

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't know the format of date/time representation you have, how can you expect to parse it? None of your patterns seems to match with the example. As K.C. said it can be a interval.

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2202300/1237297) as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
    String dateString = "2013-06-19T12:00-05:00";
    String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ";
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern);
    DateTime dateTime = dtf.parseDateTime(dateString);
    Date ans=dateTime.toDate();
    System.out.println(ans);
```

Comment: I believe this is only available for Java 7.

Comment: yes, its the same in java 6 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: I already tried `X` but it gives `IllegalArgumentException`. As @singh.jagmohan said `X` is only available in Java 7

Comment: I am still getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'X'`. This is my VM: `java version "1.6.0_22"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.6) (6b22-1.10.6-0ubuntu1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode, sharing)`

Comment: Down voted because the solution does not work and should not work per the documentation. Java 6 docs show Z is for time zone in format of "-0800" but your example has time zone "-05:00" <-- note the colon between the 5 and 0.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you use the excellent Joda-Time library to do this, specifically the `parse(String str)` method of the `DateTime` class, which will parse your example date using the default `ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser()`

The JavaDoc for `DateTime.parse(String str)` is at http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29 and you can read more about Joda-Time at http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: Using `Joda-Time` seems to be an overkill. In `Java 6` the problem can be resolved simply by adding `timezone`. Please see my answer using `regex` to do this.

Comment: Joda-Time provides a **much** nicer API to use than the standard Java 6 date/time API, so I would always use it in preference to the standard API. Joda-Time also has further benefits such as the ability to control what the 'current' time is, which is very useful for unit testing time-sensitive code.

Answer (score 1):

Use simpledateformat with pattern like "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH-mm:ss:SS"

Answer (score 0):

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library is already built to handle that variation of [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. No need to create a [formatter](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

I arbitrarily chose [Montréal Québec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal) as a time zone because of your -05:00 time zone offset. You may rather work with UTC/GMT date-times in which case you can pass a pre-defined instance: `DateTimeZone.UTC`.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;

String dateTimeString = "2013-06-19T12:00-05:00";
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ); // Or for UTC/GMT, use: DateTimeZone.UTC

DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( dateTimeString, timeZone );
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "dateTimeString: " + dateTimeString );
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "dateTime in UTC/GMT: " + dateTime.toDateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC ) );
```

When run…

```
dateTimeString: 2013-06-19T12:00-05:00
dateTime: 2013-06-19T13:00:00.000-04:00
dateTime in UTC/GMT: 2013-06-19T17:00:00.000Z
```

Note the one hour difference because Montréal Québec was in [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) on that date.

Comment: I found using `Joda-Time` to be an overkill. In `Java 6` the problem can be resolved basically by adding `timezone`. Please see my answer using `regex` to add `timezone`.

Comment: I find Joda-Time so useful that it's the first library I add to any new project.

Answer (score 0):

The date `2013-06-19T12:00-05:00` can't be parsed under Java 6 in current form. On other hand using Joda-Time seems to be an overkill.

To solve problem I added timezone to the date:

```
public Date extractDate(String dateStr) {

    Pattern aPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+([+-]\\d+:\\d+)$", Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = aPattern.matcher(dateStr);

    if(matcher.find()){
        String timezone = matcher.group(1);
        System.out.println("timezone:" + timezone);
        dateStr = StringUtils.replace(dateStr, timezone, "GMT" + timezone);
    }

    Date date = null;
    String [] datePatterns = {"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ"};
    try {
        date = DateUtils.parseDateStrictly(dateStr, datePatterns);
    }
    catch (Exception except) {          
        except.printStackTrace();           
    }
    return date;
}
```

Comment: How can you say that a one-liner with Joda-Time is overkill and then propose a hand-written function with over a dozen lines? `DateUtils.parseDateStrictly()` is part of an external library - Apache Commons - why do you feel that making use of that is not overkill but that using Joda-Time is? With Joda-Time your entire function can be replaced with just `Date date = DateTime.parse(dateStr).toDate();`

Comment: @azordi apache commons is a library that I use extensively. It's not limited to handling dates. I didn't want to pull a whole 3rd party library that only deals  with date. I would have done that if I was writing a calendar application.